# Understanding design patterns using Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

If we have an array in Java like this-

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

Then, it's sorted like this-

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Instead of this, if we had a LinkedList-

```
LinkedList <Integer> ll = new LinkedList();
```

We'd sort it like this-

```
 Collections.sort(ll);
```

How can this be explained using design patterns? Why this design and is it of a particular type? Why not just have a method in the array just like we have methods to add elements-

```
arr.sort();
ll.sort();
```

I want to understand the internal object oriented design rationale for having Arrays and Collections to sort, rather than the objects themselves having a method.

Comment: Don't assume libraries, even standard libraries, are well designed. Even if something is well-designed, that in no way suggests that it can be rationalized as an application of design patterns, let alone that the designers explicitly used design patterns to guide the design. (Conversely, using design patterns does not imply that a design is good.)

Comment: What @DerekElkins said.  Using well-known design patterns doesn't guarantee a good design, nor does good design require well-known design patterns.

Comment: The rationale here is two-fold: not to pile too many features into something simple like an array or a collection, and a missing language feature in Java like C#'s extension methods which allows to use the `object.method` syntax , but without adding the code for sorting into each collection class.

Comment: My question does not assume it's well designed, but it does assume there is some rationale behind the decision. I would like to understand the rationale.

Comment: What makes you believe the quality of the design is not the rationale?

Answer (score 4):

It's simply that the Java designers wished to keep arrays as very simple data types, and let classes such as ArrayList abstract over them. As such, arrays have no methods (except those inherited from Object), and one field (length). This is one step up from C, where arrays' equivalent is pointers to variable numbers of elements on the heap, and they don't even have a size field or bound checking.

As to your second question as to why we can't have List.sort - [we can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). It's simply not defined in list implementations, but in the List interface, as a default method. The reason there is also Collections.sort is because default methods weren't added until Java 8, and making each list implementation implement sort would result in duplicate code

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Java does not have any instance methods (except the ones inherited from `Object` which all object have). There is no common `Array` base class which arrays are instances of, rather they are instances of the specific array type, e.g. `int[]`, `String[]` etc. which are handled specially by the compiler. So basically there is no place to define instance methods for arrays.

Given arrays don't support instance methods, it is natural to place operations like `Sort` in a separate utility class. So this is not because of any specific design pattern, but because of constraints in the language design.